# httpd.conf timeout parameter change effecting ELB

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, cloud

Does changing the timeout parameter in httpd.conf can effect the performance of ELB in AWS? 
I want to increase the timeout from 60 secs to 120 seconds in httpd.conf. I dont want anything abnormal happening to ELB once I change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not affect the ELB in any way, but you will not get the desired effect. The ELB has a timeout of 60 seconds by default, if the instance behind it hasn't responded in this time the client will get a `Gateway Timeout HTTP 504` from the ELB. So you need to increase also that ELB timeout to the same value to benefit from increasing your `Timeout` on your web server. More details here: [ELB Idle Timeout](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/). 
On the other hand if it is about the `KeepAliveTimeout` from httpd.conf, this is something different. When you connect to your website through an ELB, this will open 2 connections: one with the client and one with the instance behind it where your web server is. And if you want to reuse those connections with your backend instance you need to set `KeepAlive` to `On` and the value of `KeepAliveTimeout` + `Timeout` to be bigger than the `Idle Timeout` from the ELB, so the ELB will be the one managing those reusable connections and not the backend instance. [KeepAliveTimeout](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/redhat8/rhl-rg-en-8.0/s1-apache-config.html) is the timeout after the request has been served to wait until to close the connection, so INMHO a value of 10-15 seconds will do. Also please note that putting KeepAlive to `On` will decrease the CPU consumption - less connections to create, but it will increase the memory usage - you will have some alive connections just waiting for clients. More details on [keep alive settings with ELB here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-idle-timeout.html)

Comment: Alright! But on various places I saw that time timeout on the instance should be greater than or equal to ELB's timeout, which means it must be having some purpose if something like this is mentioned.

Comment: You might be talking about the keep alive timeout (KeepAliveTimeout in httpd.conf) which should always be bigger than the ELB timeout when Keep Alive is set to True. If it is bigger than the ELB timeout then the ELB is the one managing the connections and reusing them and the instance will not close them before the ELB. Which will actually mean less CPU usage on your web server because less connections have to be created. If this is it then I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually KeepAliveTimeout is the timeout from after the request has been served, so it should have a value of just a couple of seconds (10-15) - default value is 15. So normally the server will wait for the Timeout until it returns the response and this should be equal to ELB Idle Timeout, while the KeepAliveTimeout will start after the response has been send - the server will keep the connection alive for that period so the ELB can reuse it.